# export pivot table to R

Tags: r, export, pivot-table

I have a very large dataset to which I can only access by a pivot table in Excel.

I would like to access to the raw database to work with R.

I have tried several things:

- To copy and paste in both, text and excel files, the pivot database and then import to R : It does not work. its shows only the filters that I have selected but not the totality of the database
- to click on any cell of the pivot table to see the underlying data : It only shows the first 1000 entries. This is by far the best result that I have got, the only problem is that I get the first 1000 entries and I need all of them.

What I have been doing just until now is to select the variables that interest me, then, I copy them to a new sheet and finally  I export to R. But I always forget a variable and its very expensive in time  to redo all this procedure everyday.

Does anyone know how can I access to the totality of a database from a pivot table in Excel?

I hope I have been clear, do nto hesitate to ask for more information if needed.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: To me, *"totality of a database"* means the data that informs the pivot table, meaning the regular table on which the pivot table is defined. Perhaps it's just a difference in words, but to verify: you are trying to copy the summary statistics within the pivot table, not the underlying table, right?

Comment: I do not know if I understood your question. I am trying to get the "raw" database, that is, the original columns that were used to create this pivot table.

Comment: I think (though am not certain) that the data on which the pivot table is based should be within the same workbook. If you don't know what it is, then you can find out what Excel thinks it is with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-source-data-for-a-pivottable-afd93524-f7de-432c-84d0-3896fbbc2577. Once you know the name of the named region or the range of cells, then you can use either [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/) or [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/) to extract just that data.

Comment: I does not seem to work reading the pivot table with R. It only show the variables that I have selected in the pivot table. First thing first: I have a  Pivot table, for which I do not have access to the raw data (which comes from an external server) . That is, I can change the pivot table in Excel, but that is all I can do.

I am hoping to find a way to read the raw data preferably using R since it is pretty long working with the pivot table.

Comment: I do not know what you have tried. If you look again `openxlsx::readWorkbook`, it has options to specify `sheet=`, `startRow=`, `rows=`, `cols=`, which, when used together, give you access to load as much or as little of a worksheet as you want. If in doubt, try loading more rows/cols than you think you need, then clean up the `data.frame`.